# Autocomplete based on tags JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, search, tags, match

I am trying to create a plain JavaScript function that compares user input against an array of tags and returns the best match. I have created a JSON index like this:

```json
[
    {
        "data-governance": {
            "tags": ["data", "governance"],
            "href": "data-governance.html"
        }
    },
    {
        "data-quality": {
            "tags": ["data", "quality"],
            "href": "data-quality.html"
        }
    }
]
```

I would like the function to behave as follows: if the user inputs `"data"` it should return both the *data-governance* and *data-quality* href attributes. However, if the user inputs `"data gov"` it should return the *data-governance* href attribute only.

I have found a few examples where autocompletion is done using string matching in RegEx, but none comparing an array of strings (i.e., tags).

Hopefully someone can point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```js
const data = [
   {
      'data-governance': {
          tags: ['data', 'governance'],
          href: 'data-governance.html',
       },
   },
   {
      'data-quality': {
         tags: ['data', 'quality'],
         href: 'data-quality.html',
      },
   },
];

const findMatches = (items, tag) => {
  return items
     .filter((item) => {
        const { tags } = Object.values(item)[0];
        return tags.includes(tag);
     })
     .map((item) => Object.keys(item)[0]);
};

console.log(findMatches(data, "data"));
```